# Peskin and Schroeder's argument on Yukawa Potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, fermions

I am reading Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book and a specific section on Yukawa Potential (P121, Chapter 4). In equation 4.119, when calculating the scattering amplitude, they have two Feynman diagrams contribution and hence two terms in the scattering amplitude. However, once we go to the section called "The Yukawa Potential", on the second paragraph, they say:

> If the two interacting particles are distinguishable, only the first diagram in (4.119) contributes.

I am kind of confused here. Can someone explain to me why the contribution from the second term is just dropped here?

Comment: Consider the average calculation after the eq. (4.118). If you have different particles, you can contract $\psi$-operators in one way (say, you have $\psi$ and $\Psi$), whereas in case of indistinguishable particles there are two ways to contract

Comment: Sorry I did not quite follow your answer. I read the part you pointed me to, and all I understood is how the "minus" sign appears in the process of contracting the $\psi$ operators. Could you elaborate more on how it explains the omission of the second term? Thank you.

Comment: If the particles are distinguishable then there are no contractions possible leading to the second diagram. I believe this is what @ArtemAlexandrov is saying as well.

Comment: @Oбжорoв , Yes, it is

Comment: I got it now. Thanks to both of you.